# how to get the last three elements from the string array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string array in c#.Now as per my requirement i have to get the last ,second last and one element before second last elements in string but i am not getting how to get it.
Here is my string array.With Last() i am able to get the last element but second last and before second last i am not getting to find out.

```
 string[] arrstr = str.Split(' ');
```

With `.Last()` i am able to get the last element but rest of the elements i am not able to get.
Please help me..

Comment: @Xaruth: Ah, I see. Wasn't aware the minimum for close votes as that high, rather than in the lower hundreds.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use:

```
  string[] arrstr = str.Reverse().Take(3).Reverse().ToArray();
```

In more recent versions of c# you can now use:

```
  string[] arrstr = str.TakeLast(3).ToArray();
```

Comment: There is now a .TakeLast(3) method available in LINQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takelast?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 3):

It actually gets the  number of elements and skip the remaining element from the total count and take the specified amount
you can replace the 3 with N and use as method

```
string[] res = arrstr.Skip(Math.Max(0, arrstr.Count() - 3)).Take(3).ToArray();
```

Comment: A `.ToArray()` is missing there, right? Also, there should be some kind of an explanation.

Comment: Take does not return `string[]` but `IEnumerable<string>`...

Answer (score 2):

```
var threeLastElments = arrstr.Reverse().Take(3).Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: what's the difference with thumbmunkeys's answer ?

Comment: where is the up-vote? OK so because this one is a few seconds later?

Answer (score 1):

Get a substring:`string arrstr = str.Substring(str.Length - 4, 3);`

[More on C# strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you calculate the length using obj.length; and then use arr[i] inside the loop and start the loop from last value.

Comment: `int len = arrstr.length;

for(int i= len ; i>= len-2; i--)
   {
   int j = 0;
  String[] newArr = new String[3];
  newArr[j] = arrstr[i];
   j++;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

To offer another solution, one which will be much more performant than LINQ queries ...

```
 public static string[] getLast3(string[] src)
    {
        if (src.Length <= 3)
            return src;
        var res = new string[3];
        Array.Copy(src, src.Length - 3, res, 0, 3);
        return res;
    }
```